# maven-jar-plugin to specify mainClass

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to run a Java10 "hello world" example from the commandline that I have created using maven.

But I get the message

> Error: Could not find or load main class App in module eu.ngong.mainclass

It works with

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=eu.ngong.mainclass.App
```

but not if I run the script

```
p=~/.m2/repository/eu/ngong/mainclass/1.0.0
java -p $p -m eu.ngong.mainclass.App
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>eu.ngong</groupId>
<artifactId>mainclass</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mainclass</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>eu.ngong.mainclass.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I look into the jar, I can find the App class, as well as the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Built-By: rsc
Build-Jdk: 10.0.2
Main-Class: eu.ngong.mainclass.App
```

What did I miss?

I pushed the project [here](https://gitlab.com/ngong1/mainclass)

Comment: since your project is not multi-module one, you can simply use `<plugins>` without embedding it inside `<pluginManagement>` since usually pluginManagement is used when you have a parent pom that will be used by some child poms.

Comment: Thank you. Gimhani - I ever wondered what <pluginManagement> is good for. I never used maven for a mulit-module project, and wonder if I should learn that with the event of Jigsaw - but that is a different subject.

Answer (score 1):

Try updaing the pom with `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` as well in maven-jar-plugin as below under `configuration`. It cannot correctly find the main class when the class path is not set.

```
 <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>eu.ngong.mainclass.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
```

Comment: your answer sounds as if I have to find two places in pom for addClasspath. I can identify the one your example shows. I tried several other places without success. 
Nothing helped. What did help was a "mvn test". Afterwards "mvn exec" runs successfully. All my tests are just templates with no relation to the main class. And how should a test run influence the later execution of a jar? Hmm - I am more lost than I was before. I can repeat it as often as I like: "mvn clean; mvn exec ..." leads to failure, while "mvn clean; mvn text; mvn exec ..." runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean` deletes all compiled classes.

`mvn exec:java` runs the only the ***goal*** `java` of the plugin `exec`. But it is missing the compiled classes, that you `clean`ed before.

`mvn test` asks maven to run all lifecycles up to the test ***phase*** - including the `compile` lifecycle.

`mvn compile exec:java` would run everything including the compile phase (which should be enough for *exec:java* goal) and then the exec:java goal. You can separated it also in two calls.